# debug.keystore opens for notepad but it's for godot 3.3

Tags: android, export, keystore, godot, generate

I created a debug.keystore for Godot 3.3 with it asking how to open it and I chose notepad.

I did as much as I think it said in the docs and put it in Debug Keystore and Android Sdk Path, as I was emailed on Godot Q&A that Adb and Jarsigner are no longer required.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_android.html#create-a-debug-keystore.

Originally the file was a blank file which I had no reason to check properties of type. It looks like this now:
[It was never like this until I used the docs key generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hobni.png)
When I click it, it's all types of code, but I don't think this accepts it in this form and I get this, [apksigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txTti.png) and this [not accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yMQj.png). How do I generate this debug.keystore?

Comment: Generating the keystore as explained in the documentation should work. Binding notepad is incidental, and should not affect the process. The Godot Console Window (the CMD-eske one that by default opens with Godot) should have more information on the error. See also https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/issues/4796

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond. Thought I should wait for a bug fix, but... I would hope someone would to my ERROR. ERROR: _export_project_to_path: Failed to export the project for platform 'Android'.
   At: editor/project_export.cpp:872

Comment: To be clear the linked issue is one of the documentation. You can try the current release candidate to see if it fixes the problem for you: https://godotengine.org/article/release-candidate-godot-3-3-1-rc-2